# codeigniter php

Tags: codeigniter

I want to ask one of those broad questions so please go easy on me. I know that phil is doing well with pyrocms but I would like to use pyro for my sites and also know how to write custom additions to the cms to suit my needs so what bums me out is how do you use it? where do i add my additions? how is it laid out? Like I said before go easy with me cos there is no documentation for pyrocms.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is one for me then :-)

modules can be added to the system by adding the folder to application/modules and copying the folder structure. To understand the modular structure better read the documentation for Matchbox by Zacharius K. I'm on my iPhone on a train so not going to look I up for you :-)

look a details.XML within the module to see how to set frontend/backend module type and when you have set a module with is_backend_sidebar clear the cache (or wait 6 hours :-p).

Documentation WILL come soon, my Internet has been down 2 months longer than expected so finishing v0.9.8 then documenting the lot will take a while.

Tweet or email me for more help.

Comment: Phil,

don't want to make you uneasy so I really am grateful for your short answer here. I will read up on the match box docs and see how far I can go. Keep up the good work and I hope you have good speed with pyro and all else.

Cheers

Comment: PyroCMS has hit v0.9.8-beta1 so is a perfect time to have a play if you are still interested. The modular system has changed to Modular Separation and the module directory has moved to application/modules/third_party. Look at other modules for changes, I'll be writing up a "Upgrade your modules" guide as part of the documentation.